# Are identify this questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have an old mainboard here, which runs, but I don't have a manual or documentation for the jumper settings. Would a question to identify and document this board be on topic?

Answer (score 6):

Yes.  We have an [identify-this-computer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-computer) tag for questions such as this.

Give as much information as you can about the machine:  Pictures, description, etc.  The more you can give, the more likely you are to get a good answer.