# New Tag: [tag:Identify-This]

Tags: discussion, feature-request, specific-tag

I just posted [a question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/7716/what-is-that-slot-on-the-bottom-of-an-exidy-sorcerer) to identify a feature of an Exidy Sorcerer's case I can't explain. Categorizing that kind of question seems hard, as it's not a computer or game to be identified, but a feature. Then again, it doesn't make much sense to add an  [identify-this-feature](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-feature) tag. Thus a more generic [identify-this](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this) to cover all the less common identify-this type outside the big other categories would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Why not make it a noun in line with other SE sites?

[EarthScience.SE](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) uses [identification-request](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request)

This also avoids the 'linguistic' suggestion to add things that is implicit in using [identify-this](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this) (as mentioned in [chenmuka's answer](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/656/8725)).

I would even suggest to combine all [identify-this-xxx](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-xxx) into [identification-request](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) - the number of ID questions does not really call for separate categories.

Comment: Works as well - except, I'd keep the two existing tags, as they cover what's eventually may be the majority of questions in a good way

Answer (score 1):

Certainly *Identify this* questions are on topic, after more than one confirmation question already here on meta...
[Are identify this questions on topic?](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/578/276)

I am in two minds about [identify-this](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this) without a suffix as being a bit broad.  It would certainly need a wiki that mentions the existing [identify-this-computer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-computer) and [identify-this-game](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game) tags.

However, on the other hand, if we start allowing [identify-this-feature](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-feature) we will get [identify-this-socket](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-socket), [identify-this-gismo](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-gismo) ad nauseam.

So, I would say let's do it.  Add [identify-this](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this).

Comment: Also, at least on the browser I use, typing in a tag displays all starting with the same string, so identify-this would come up togeter with identify-this-computer  identify-this-game, reminding the user to select something apropriate. Each of these has a help text below, so if theis clearly states that  identify-this  is only to be used if no other cathergory fits, then It might work out, do't you think so?